Identifying the max in a group using PowerQuery
I have a table:



trip_id
stop_sequence




Y1
1


Y1
2


Y1
3


Y1
4


Y1
5


Y2
1


Y2
2


Y2
3


Y2
4



I want to add a custom column that has a value of TRUE for the record which has the highest value of stop_sequence within a group that is grouped by trip_id.
In my case, the 5th and 9th row will have TRUE.
What should be the expression of the custom column?

let a = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (x)=> x[trip_id] = [trip_id]),
b = List.Max(a[stop_sequence])
in if b = [stop_sequence] then true else null




Different approach using Table.Group and Table.NestedJoinmight be slightly faster on very large data sets
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WijRU0lEyVIrVgTKNEExjBNMEwTSFMI0Q2owQ2owQ2owg2mIB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [trip_id = _t, stop_sequence = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"trip_id", type text}, {"stop_sequence", Int64.Type}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"trip_id"}, {{"Max Seq", each List.Max([stop_sequence]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Join" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type","trip_id",#"Grouped Rows","trip_id","Join",JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    #"Add Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Join","Custom", each 
        if [stop_sequence] = [Join]{0}[Max Seq] 
            then true 
            else null, 
            type nullable logical),
            
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Custom",{"Join"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

Source Data

Results

